# Do I need sugar for zabaglione?

Tags: eggs, sugar, foam

I want to make zabaglione and think that the taste could benefit if I sweeten it with honey instead of sugar. But I am not sure whether the sugar crystals have a physical effect on the fluffing up. Can I do it, or will it be flatter without the sugar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honey, for me, makes zabaglione terribly heavy. However, you can buy Crumiel, a dehydrated honey product from the Texturas line by Albert and Ferran Adria. My understanding is that it can essentially be used as a substitute for sugar while retaining the honey flavour.

Comment: Nice, I'll try this thing someday. For now, I used sugar, but substituted the dessert wine for Grand Marnier to get a new taste.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this before and found it made the custard heavy and a little too sweet (even though I didn't add as much honey as sugar). I don't think the crystals assist in the "fluffing up" process, but I think the lighter weight keeps the mixture light yet creamy.